# ajax parsing from JSON.stringify(Data)

Tags: ajax, json

I have the following ajax as you see below:

```
  $.ajax({

     url: url,

    type: 'POST',

    dataType: 'json',

    data: JSON.stringify(json),

    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

    success: function (Data) {



        alert(JSON.stringify(Data));



    },

    error: error

});
```

When I do  alert(JSON.stringify(Data));
it shows the data that see below. Data is the object I am sending back. It is returing 3 rows with 4 columns. How do I iterate through the data from the stringify as I need to store it into an HTML table?

```
{"Data":[{"Iden":"12","Date":"01/23/2011","City":"Clearwater","State":"FL"},{"Iden":"19","Date":"02/09/2012","City":"Elgin","State":"IL"},{"Iden":"14","Date":"06/22/2010","City":"Newport Beach","State":"CA"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the jQuery each function:

```
$.each( Data, function(index, element){
    alert( "Index: " + index + ", Element: " + element );
});
```

Comment: when i try this i am getting the index as 0,1,2...and element as each char....dont know what am i  doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Before passing it to $.each function you have to parse JSON data

```
var d = JSON.parse(Data);


You can also directly call like this too

$.each( d.Data, function(index, element){
    alert( "Index: " + index + ", Element: " + element );
});

For ex if the json is like this
{"note":{"to":"Tove","from":"Jani","heading":"Reminder","body":"Don&apos;t forget me this weekend!"}}

$.each( d.note, function(index, element){
     alert( "Index: " + index + ", Element: " + element );
});
```